# python & suds "ImportError: cannot import name getLogger"

Tags: python, suds, importerror

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 (natty).  I have been using Suds to consume a SOAP web service. Everything was working fine... until it wasn't. I can no longer import Suds. I've uninstalled and re-installed Suds from the Ubuntu repositories but still get the same import error (see IDLE traceback below). I'm using Python 2.7.1 and Suds 0.4.1-2.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem??

```
>>> import suds

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import suds
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/suds/__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
    import client
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/suds/client.py", line 23, in <module>
    import suds.metrics as metrics
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/suds/metrics.py", line 23, in <module>
    from logging import getLogger
ImportError: cannot import name getLogger
>>>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`logging` is a standard module of Python. There are several possible reasons why Python can't find it anymore:

1. The is another `logging` module in the path (print `sys.path` to get a list of paths Python will search)
2. Someone changed `PYTHONPATH` (the default Python search path)
3. Someone messed with the Python installation (deleted the `logging` module)

Comment: Thank you! It was answer number 1. I had written a module called 'log.py' which I later renamed to 'logging.py'. Should have realised this (embarrassing). Thanks for answering my question so quickly.