# Logging; ImportError: cannot import name 'get_logger' from 'logger'

Tags: python, logging, get, importerror

I've got a Python script from a friend who is not in available at the moment.
Unfortunately i am not able run it.

Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_logger' from 'logger' (C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\logger\__init__.py)
```

I can locate the file `__init__.py` at the mentioned path.

Part of the script which causes this error:

```
import time
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from requests.api import post
import os
import traceback
from logger import get_logger       #<----- Error
from datetime import date

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
logging = get_logger(dir_path)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger = logging.getLogger()     
[...]
```

Code of `__init__.py`:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import os
import sys
import types

logging.getLogger('paramiko').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger('requests').setLevel(logging.WARNING)

config_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'logging.conf')

logging.config.fileConfig(config_file, disable_existing_loggers=False)
logger = logging.getLogger()


def error(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
    self.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
    sys.exit(1)

logger.interrupt = types.MethodType(error, logger)
logger.info = logger.info
logger.warn = logger.warn
```

I hope you guys can help me to solve this issue.
Thanks!

What i tried

- Googled ImportError: cannot import name 'get_logger' from 'logger'  - Answere was based on another issue ([ImportError: cannot import name 'getLogger'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127794/importerror-cannot-import-name-getlogger))
- Tried to directly import logging instead of logger
- No idea what else i should try since i usually do not develope (Hi from sales)